# Threaded DES slower than not threaded

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am having trouble to get performance improvement by parallelizing a DES encryption algorithm.

Here is my attempt:

```
fn des(message: &[u8], subkeys: Vec<u64>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut pool = Pool::new(THREAD_COUNT);
    let message = message_to_u64s(message);

    crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
        pool.map(scope, message.iter().enumerate(), |(i, &block)| {
            let permuted = ip(block);
            let mut li = permuted & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;
            let mut ri = permuted << 32;

            for subkey in &subkeys {
                let last_li = li;
                li = ri;
                ri = last_li ^ feistel(ri, *subkey);
            }

            let r16l16 = ri | (li >> 32);
            to_u8_vec(fp(r16l16))
        }).collect::<Vec<_>>()
    }).concat()
}
```

(this uses the crates `crossbeam` and `simple_parallel` but I will accept solutions not using these)

Unfortunately, this implementation is slower than the version without thread:

```
fn des(message: &[u8], subkeys: Vec<u64>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let message = message_to_u64s(message);

    let mut cipher = vec![];

    for block in message {
        let permuted = ip(block);
        let mut li = permuted & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;
        let mut ri = permuted << 32;

        for subkey in &subkeys {
            let last_li = li;
            li = ri;
            ri = last_li ^ feistel(ri, *subkey);
        }

        let r16l16 = ri | (li >> 32);
        let mut bytes = to_u8_vec(fp(r16l16));
        cipher.append(&mut bytes);
    }

    cipher
}
```

I believe the `collect` and `concat` are the issues but I don't know how to avoid them without using unsafe code.

So how can I improve the performance of this algorithm (by using threads) using safe code?
(solutions with unsafe code would also be interesting, but I believe there must be a solution without unsafe code)

Comment: Is this 1 thread per byte? I can imagine the overhead of the threads spinning up is whats causing the slowdown based on the input.

Comment: Seems like it would be simpler to use `&[u8]` and `&[u64]` everywhere rather than `Vec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a profiler. You could try guessing where the slowdown is, but in you may not find the right place anyway.

But for an educated guess... I'd try splitting the message into `THREAD_COUNT` parts and feeding those parts to the thread pool instead. If you're sending 8-byte fragments separately, you'll spend more time on managing that than on the DES itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You were right: I had to split the message. I tried `valgrind` to profile the application but it only tells that most of the time is spent in the closure of the thread: how can I guess your solution from such a profiling result?

Comment: Interesting... I haven't tried profiling threaded rust yet. If you get only the closure listed, not collects, etc. this may be a good question on its own. Ideally per-line profile would be useful here.

Comment: viraptor: I had not compiled with debug symbols. With them, I see more function calls but I am still not sure how to guess this issue. One noticeable difference I saw between the two `valgrind` outputs is that the closure is called a lot of time with my initial version. I think this is the way to tell that too many threads were used, right? Thanks.